# Relaunching application via NSTask ignores LSMinimumSystemVersionByArchitecture

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstask

I'm running into an issue with relaunching my application on 10.5.  In my Info.plist I have LSMinimumSystemVersionByArchitecture set so that the application will run in 64-bit for x86_64 and 32-bit on i386, ppc, and ppc64.

I have a preference in the app that allows the user to switch between a Dock icon & NSStatusItem, and it prompts the user to relaunch the app once they change the setting using using the following code:

```
id fullPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] executablePath];
NSArray *arg = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil];    
[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:fullPath arguments:arg];
[NSApp terminate:self];
```

When this executes on 10.5, however it relaunches the application in 64-bit which is not a desired result for me.   From what I gather reading the docs its because the LS* keys are not read when the app is launched via command line.

Is there a way around this?  I tried doing something like below, which worked on 10.6, but on 10.5 it was chirping at me that the "launch path not accessible".  ([NSApp isOnSnowLeopardOrBetter] is a category that checks the AppKit version number).

```
id path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] executablePath];    
NSString *fullPath = nil;
if (![NSApp isOnSnowLeopardOrBetter])      
  fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/usr/bin/arch -i386 -ppc %@", path];
else    
  fullPath = path;

NSArray *arg = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil];    
[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:fullPath arguments:arg];
[NSApp terminate:self];
```

Comment: You get “launch path not accessible” because “/usr/bin/arch -i386 -ppc /Applications/YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/YourApp” is not a path of an executable file on your system. NSTask does not use the shell; you need to pass it the path of the executable you want to run (/usr/bin/arch) and the list of arguments *separately*, with the arguments also separate from each other, collected in an NSArray.

Answer (score 2):

You should instead use the methods of [`NSWorkspace`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which does take into account `Info.plist` keys. For example, use `-(BOOL)launchApplication:(NSString*)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use spaces inside fullpath, use arguments within an array `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"/usr/bin/arch",@"-i386",@"-ppc",path,nil]`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code for relaunch your app:

```
//terminate your app in some of your method:
[[NSApplication sharedApplication]terminate:nil];

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification {

    if (i need to restart my app) {

       NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
       [task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/open"];
       [task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"/Applications/MyApp.app", nil]];
       [task launch];
   }
}
```